# Object - orientation

Tags: python

```
class Mammal(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def say(self):
        print("What does the " + self.name + " says")
```

The above is my code

when I tried `print(Mammal("Fox").say())` I get `What does the Fox says` which is correct but I am getting another additional `None` . What is the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the method `say` returns None, it simply prints something
None is what is returned by a method in python if it does not have a return statement described

```
>>> print (Mammal("Fox").say())
None

>>> def a():
...     return True
>>> def b():
...     pass
>>> print(a())
True
>>> print(b())
None
```

However, if you want to be more pythonic, you should make your `say` method return the string rather than say it as follows:

```
def say(self):
    return "What does the " + self.name + " says"
```

That way you only get the string when you call the method and don't actually print anything:

```
>>> print(Mammal("Fox").say())
What does the Fox says
```

However, if you want to stick with printing from the method, you can do it as follows:

```
Mammal("Fox").say()
```

or:

```
fox = Mammal('Fox')
fox.say()
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `say()` returns `None`. It also prints a string itself.

Try:

```
Mammal("Fox").say()
```

Another thing to try is extract the string to a method:

```
def what_should_i_say(self):
    return "What does the " + self.name + " says"
def say(self):
    print self.what_should_i_say()
```

and then

```
print Mammal("Fox").what_should_i_say()
Mammal("Giraffe").say()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Mammal("Fox").say()
```

is all you need.

Mammal("Fox").say() returns None so you are effectively typing:

```
print(None)
```

It just so happens it print the saying to calculate that .say() returns None.

Answer (score 0):

You have added an extra `print`.  `Mammal("Fox").say()` should work.